# browsing image from android device through application getting error

Tags: android, image

I want to select an image from device by application browse button.On button click the device popups for the application to finish the selection. If I choose any image viewer no issues but if I choose file manager then force close

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Atleast Post Log or some related code to find the errors